# C++: how to input values separated by comma(,)

Tags: c++, cin, getline

```
int a, b, c, d;
```

There are 4 variables.

I want user to input 4 values, and each value is separated by comma(,)

Just like this:

> **stdin:**
>
> 1,2,3,4

The following code works in C

```
scanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);
```

But how should I code in C++?

Comment: C++ is essentially an extension of C: `sscanf("%d,%d,%d,%d", &a, &b, &c, &d);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m kind of surprised at the incorrect commentary here<sup>[1]</sup>.

There are two basic routes you can take:

- handle the separator with a manipulator-style object, or
- imbue the stream with a specialized facet that requires whitespace to include a comma.

I will focus on the first; it is typically a bad idea to imbue shared streams with weird behaviors even temporarily (“shared” in the sense that other parts of your code have access to it as well; a local stringstream would be an ideal candidate for imbuing with specialized behaviors).

A ‘next item must be a comma’ extractor:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

struct extract
{
  char c;
  extract( char c ): c(c) { }
};

std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, extract e )
{
  // Skip leading whitespace IFF user is not asking to extract a whitespace character
  if (!std::isspace( e.c )) ins >> std::ws;

  // Attempt to get the specific character
  if (ins.peek() == e.c) ins.get();

  // Failure works as always
  else ins.setstate( std::ios::failbit );

  return ins;
}

int main()
{
  int a, b;
  std::cin >> a >> extract(',') >> b;
  if (std::cin)
    std::cout << a << ',' << b << "\n";
  else
    std::cout << "quiznak.\n";
}
```

Running this code, the `extract` manipulator/extractor/whatever will succeed only if the next non-whitespace item is a comma. It fails otherwise.

You can easily modify this to make the comma optional:

```
std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& ins, optional_extract e )
{
  // Skip leading whitespace IFF user is not asking to extract a whitespace character
  if (!std::isspace( e.c )) ins >> std::ws;

  // Attempt to get the specific character
  if (ins.peek() == e.c) ins.get();

  // There is no failure!
  return ins;
}

...

std::cin >> a >> optional_extract(',') >> b;
```

Etc.

[1] `cin >> a >> b;` is *not* equivalent to `scanf( "%d,%d", ...);`. C++ does not magically ignore commas. Just as in C, you must treat them explicitly.

The same for the answer using `getline()` and a `stringstream`; while the combination is valid, the actual problem is just shifted from `std::cin` to another stream object, and still must be treated.